# Neo4j 2.2.3 throwing the following error in console.log

Tags: neo4j

Number of open files (lsof | wc -l): 20484

ulimit is unlimited

Console.log

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/centos/neo4j-community-2.2.3/data/graph.db/schema/label/lucene/_179hu.fdt (Permission denied)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_85]
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:241) ~[na:1.7.0_85]
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory$FSIndexOutput.<init>(FSDirectory.java:441) ~[lucene-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2 1423725 - rmuir - 2012-12-18 19:45:40]
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.createOutput(FSDirectory.java:306) ~[lucene-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2 1423725 - rmuir - 2012-12-18 19:45:40]
    at org.apache.lucene.index.FieldsWriter.<init>(FieldsWriter.java:83) ~[lucene-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2 1423725 - rmuir - 2012-12-18 19:45:40]
    at org.apache.lucene.index.StoredFieldsWriter.initFieldsWriter(StoredFieldsWriter.java:64) ~[lucene-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2 1423725 - rmuir - 2012-12-18 19:45:40]
    at org.apache.lucene.index.StoredFieldsWriter.finishDocument(StoredFieldsWriter.java:107) ~[lucene-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2 1423725 - rmuir - 2012-12-18 19:45:40]
    at org.apache.lucene.index.StoredFieldsWriter$PerDoc.finish(StoredFieldsWriter.java:151) ~[lucene-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2 1423725 - rmuir - 2012-12-18 19:45:40]
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter$WaitQueue.writeDocument(DocumentsWriter.java:1404) ~[lucene-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2 1423725 - rmuir - 2012-12-18 19:45:40]
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter$WaitQueue.add(DocumentsWriter.java:1424) ~[lucene-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2 1423725 - rmuir - 2012-12-18 19:45:40]
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.finishDocument(DocumentsWriter.java:1043) ~[lucene-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2 1423725 - rmuir - 2012-12-18 19:45:40]
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.updateDocument(DocumentsWriter.java:772) ~[lucene-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2 1423725 - rmuir - 2012-12-18 19:45:40]
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocument(IndexWriter.java:2328) ~[lucene-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2 1423725 - rmuir - 2012-12-18 19:45:40]
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocument(IndexWriter.java:2300) ~[lucene-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2 1423725 - rmuir - 2012-12-18 19:45:40]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.LuceneIndexWriter.updateDocument(LuceneIndexWriter.java:67) ~[neo4j-lucene-index-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.TrackingLuceneIndexWriter.updateDocument(TrackingLuceneIndexWriter.java:55) ~[neo4j-lucene-index-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.LuceneLabelScanStore.updateDocument(LuceneLabelScanStore.java:150) ~[neo4j-lucene-index-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.LuceneLabelScanWriter.flush(LuceneLabelScanWriter.java:156) ~[neo4j-lucene-index-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.LuceneLabelScanWriter.write(LuceneLabelScanWriter.java:75) ~[neo4j-lucene-index-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.command.IndexTransactionApplier$LabelUpdateWork.apply(IndexTransactionApplier.java:139) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/centos/neo4j-community-2.2.3/data/graph.db/schema/label/lucene/_179hv.fdt (Permission denied)
            at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_85]
            at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:241) ~[na:1.7.0_85]
            at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory$FSIndexOutput.<init>(FSDirectory.java:441) ~[lucene-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2 1423725 - rmuir - 2012-12-18 19:45:40]
            at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.createOutput(FSDirectory.java:306) ~[lucene-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2 1423725 - rmuir - 2012-12-18 19:45:40]
            at org.apache.lucene.index.FieldsWriter.<init>(FieldsWriter.java:83) ~[lucene-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2 1423725 - rmuir - 2012-12-18 19:45:40]
            at org.apache.lucene.index.StoredFieldsWriter.initFieldsWriter(StoredFieldsWriter.java:64) ~[lucene-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2 1423725 - rmuir - 2012-12-18 19:45:40]
            at org.apache.lucene.index.StoredFieldsWriter.finishDocument(StoredFieldsWriter.java:107) ~[lucene-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2 1423725 - rmuir - 2012-12-18 19:45:40]
            at org.apache.lucene.index.StoredFieldsWriter$PerDoc.finish(StoredFieldsWriter.java:151) ~[lucene-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2 1423725 - rmuir - 2012-12-18 19:45:40]
            at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter$WaitQueue.writeDocument(DocumentsWriter.java:1404) ~[lucene-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2 1423725 - rmuir - 2012-12-18 19:45:40]
            at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter$WaitQueue.add(DocumentsWriter.java:1424) ~[lucene-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2 1423725 - rmuir - 2012-12-18 19:45:40]
            at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.finishDocument(DocumentsWriter.java:1043) ~[lucene-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2 1423725 - rmuir - 2012-12-18 19:45:40]
            at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.updateDocument(DocumentsWriter.java:772) ~[lucene-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2 1423725 - rmuir - 2012-12-18 19:45:40]
            at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocument(IndexWriter.java:2328) ~[lucene-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2 1423725 - rmuir - 2012-12-18 19:45:40]
            at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocument(IndexWriter.java:2300) ~[lucene-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2 1423725 - rmuir - 2012-12-18 19:45:40]
            at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.LuceneIndexWriter.updateDocument(LuceneIndexWriter.java:67) ~[neo4j-lucene-index-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
            at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.TrackingLuceneIndexWriter.updateDocument(TrackingLuceneIndexWriter.java:55) ~[neo4j-lucene-index-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
            at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.LuceneLabelScanStore.updateDocument(LuceneLabelScanStore.java:150) ~[neo4j-lucene-index-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
            at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.LuceneLabelScanWriter.flush(LuceneLabelScanWriter.java:156) ~[neo4j-lucene-index-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
            at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.LuceneLabelScanWriter.close(LuceneLabelScanWriter.java:87) ~[neo4j-lucene-index-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.command.IndexTransactionApplier$LabelUpdateWork.apply(IndexTransactionApplier.java:141) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
            ... 42 common frames omitted
```

Why the following error is occurring again and again? Though on reinstalling the Neo4j with a database backup things work fine for sometime.

Comment: are the permissions set for the pid user running neo4j ?

Comment: How to check that? and if its not there, then how to set the permissions?

Comment: I restarted the server as sudo. Seems to be working now. Thanks :)

Comment: I suspect that this is the neo4j user running the pid and the stores are chmod'ed to the centos group, I would try to add the neo4j user to the centos group : `useradd -G centos neo4j` . For more infos I would suggest you to check some tutorials about `unix permissions`

Comment: NB: Sudo is not a solution

Comment: ``ps -ef | grep 7474`` gives
``centos   10512  7579  0 09:32 pts/6    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 7474``

So, I think the user is centos itself?

Though I tried ``useradd -G centos neo4j ``, and server failed to start without sudo then.

Comment: Once you run it as sudo you may have changed some permission, in particular for new files if some. May be that it should be one of them. If you are running the database as neo4j run this command
chown -R centos:neo4j /home/centos/neo4j-community-2.2.3/data/graph.db/
In my opinion you are running it as user centos so may be that you should change everything to centos:centos